# Dynamic where clause in Snowflake Javascript UDTF

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a UDTF with little complex SQL queries but not able to do so as I don't know Javascript.

I am replicating the case where I need help. Could someone please write a UDTF for this which I can refer for my use case?

```
create table emp(  
  empno    number(4,0),  
  ename    varchar(10),  
  job      varchar2(9),  
  mgr      number(4,0),  
  hiredate date,  
  sal      number(7,2),  
  comm     number(7,2),  
  deptname varchar(20)
);
```

I want to put below sql query in UDTF. The UDTF will have two parameters 'hiredate' and 'deptname'. I want to make the where clause dynamic in the query which means user can pass either hiredate or deptname or both. The output returned should be table. The below sample is for SQL UDTF but I believe my requirement can be fulfilled with Javascript UDTF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE FUNCTION FN_EMP (PARAM_HIREDATE DATE, PARAM_DEPTNAME VARCHAR(20))
  RETURNS TABLE (EMPNO NUMBER,  ENAME VARCHAR(10))
  AS
  $$
    select EMPNO, ENAME 
    from emp
    where hiredate = PARAM_HIREDATE --these where clause should be applied dynamically
        and deptname = PARAM_DEPTNAME
  $$
  ;
```

Please show me how I can use If else in JavaScript UDTF (NOT UDF). Or enlighten me how can I fulfill my requirement. Could someone please write a UDTF for this which I can refer for my use case?

I already went through the 3 callback function documentation but dont know how to execute a SQL statement inside a Javascript UDTF.

My requirement is somewhat similar to this, but don't how how to execute a SQL inside Javascript UDTF.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009Fye3YSAR/have-you-got-an-example-of-a-udf-in-javascript-that-returns-a-table

Answer (score 0):

"Kitchen sink" function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE FUNCTION FN_EMP (PARAM_HIREDATE DATE,
                                          PARAM_DEPTNAME VARCHAR(20))
  RETURNS TABLE (EMPNO NUMBER,  ENAME VARCHAR(10))
  AS
  $$
    select EMPNO, ENAME 
    from emp
    where (hiredate = PARAM_HIREDATE OR PARAM_HIREDATE IS NULL)
      and (deptname = PARAM_DEPTNAME OR PARAM_DEPTNAME IS NULL)
  $$
  ;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_EMP(NULL::DATE,NULL::STIRNG));  -- no params

SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_EMP(NULL::DATE,'<deparment>'));  -- only deparment

SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_EMP(CURRENT_DATE, '<deparment>') -- both
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but it does not allow me to pass NULL in input parameter. Throws the error "SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 20 Invalid argument types for function 'FN_EMP': (NULL, NULL)"

Could you please recommend another workaround for this? Or can we do this using JavaScript?

PS - I already tried adding the optional parameter 'CALLED ON NULL INPUT' while defining the UDTF but that didn't work too.

Comment: @pratyushkumar "   SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_EMP(NULL::DATE,NULL::STIRNG));"

Answer (score 0):

@Lukasz Szozda I believe if there's no way to pass NULL in the input parameter of SQL UDTF then the below will work. But I will have to ask the users to default it to 'NA' when they do not want to pass any parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_EMP (PARAM_HIREDATE VARCHAR(50),
                                          PARAM_DEPTNAME VARCHAR(20))
  RETURNS TABLE (EMPNO NUMBER,  ENAME VARCHAR(10))
  AS
  $$
    select EMPNO, ENAME 
    from emp
    where (hiredate = TO_DATE(PARAM_HIREDATE) OR PARAM_HIREDATE = 'NA')
      and (deptname = PARAM_DEPTNAME OR PARAM_DEPTNAME = 'NA')
  $$
  ;
  
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_EMP('NA','NA'));  -- no params

SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_EMP('NA','<deparment>'));  -- only deparment

SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_EMP('2021-07-08', '<deparment>')); -- both
```